# How to get last 24 hrs data in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want  to get last 24 hrs data. i wrote a query in postgreSQL as follows. But I couldn't get the answer as i expected.

```
 SELECT startdate::timestamp AS startdate,
    (DATE_PART('hour',startdate::timestamp)::integer) as hrs,count(guorderid)
    FROM ord_entitlement
    WHERE DATE_PART('Day',CURRENT_DATE::timestamp - startdate::timestamp) < 1
    AND DATE_PART('hour',startdate::timestamp) <= 24
    GROUP BY  hrs,startdate
    ORDER BY startdate
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `CURRENT_DATE` you will not get the time instead use `now()` function. Try the following,

```
        SELECT startdate::timestamp AS startdate,
        (DATE_PART('hour',startdate::timestamp)::integer) as hrs,count(guorderid)
        FROM ord_entitlement
        WHERE DATE_PART('Day',now() - startdate::timestamptz) < 1
        GROUP BY  hrs,startdate
        ORDER BY startdate
```

Comment: Watch out, one day is not the same as 24 hours.  [Some days have 25 or 23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time#Procedure).

Comment: Thanks @Schwern its not for a country with daylight saving time.

Comment: @Pirinthan Maybe not now, but things change. Sri Lanka? Your time zone has changed three times in the last 20 years, each of those transitions may break this code.

Comment: A WHERE-condition like this, can't use an index, it's slow by design. Try this: WHERE startdate::timestamptz > NOW() - INTERVAL '24 hour'

Comment: @Schwern what do you think is best? now() or CURRENT_TIME if we consider the performance?

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon NOW vs CURRENT_TIME shouldn't make a difference. [See the discussion on my answer for performance details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405654/how-to-get-last-24-hrs-data-in-postgresql/28406345?noredirect=1#comment45149689_28406345).

Answer (score 14):

Instead of checking date parts, do the time math to get an interval.  Use NOW() to get a timestamptz.

```
SELECT startdate::timestamp AS startdate,
      (DATE_PART('hour',startdate::timestamp)::integer) as hrs, 
      count(guorderid)
FROM ord_entitlement
WHERE NOW() > startdate::timestamptz
  AND NOW() - startdate::timestamptz <= interval '24 hours'
GROUP BY hrs,startdate
ORDER BY startdate
```

This ensures you will get the last 24 hours no matter what your time zone or daylight savings says.  `NOW() > startdate::timestamptz` ensures you don't accidentally pick up things from the future.

Comment: DATE_PART isn't the problem, it's the calculation using NOW() that makes it's impossible to create an index in the first place. A function must be immutable if you want to use it in your index and NOW() isn't.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I put an index on a timestamp and did some testing.  PostgreSQL 9.4 will use the index for pretty much every technique here.

Comment: @Schwern you can see the difference [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dc9c3/1) -- the 3 condition is effectively the same, but only the last one uses the index. The rule of thumb is, one should use the index expression/column on one of the sides of the comparison.

Comment: @pozs Curious. It seems having the serial column changes the indexing behavior. I only had a timestamptz.

Comment: @pozs From what I can tell it *can* use the index for queries 1, 2 and 4, but it doesn't make the query faster so it doesn't bother. You can see this by removing the serial column and `SET enable_seqscan = off`. I still don't know why the serial column is changing the behavior.

Comment: @Schwern that's probably because [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) -- when you query only indexed columns, Postgres will not touch the table at all: it can accumulate results directly from indexes. -- Turning off `enable_seqscan` is a valid testing method of index usage, but I wouldn't use it in production; it can lead surprising results.

Answer (score 3):

`date_part()` works like `extract()`, i.e. they will [extract a subfield](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) from the source:

```
-- they will both yield 9 as result
select date_part('day', date '2015-01-09') "day part of 2015-01-09",
       date_part('day', date '2015-02-09') "day part of 2015-02-09";
```

Extracting `day(s)` therefore is not suited to select the last 24 hours. Similarly extracting `hour(s)` will (almost) always yield less than or equal to `24`.

Extraction `day(s)` from `interval` (that's the result of substracting 2 `timestamp`s) is a little different. The result might depend on, whether the interval is justified, or not:

```
-- they will both yield 1 as result
select date_part('day', interval '1 day') "day part of 1 day",
       date_part('day', interval '1 month 1 day') "day part of 1 month 1 day";


-- they will yield 1, 32 and 397 respectively
select date_part('day', timestamp '2015-02-09' - timestamp '2015-02-08') "interval 1",
       date_part('day', timestamp '2015-02-09' - timestamp '2015-01-08') "interval 2",
       date_part('day', timestamp '2015-02-09' - timestamp '2014-01-08') "interval 3";
```

Depending on the fact, that the timestamp subtraction is not giving justified intervals is not the best option, I think. You could use simpler conditions to achieve your goal:

```
-- if startdate is a timestamp:
where current_timestamp - interval '1 day' <= startdate

-- if startdate is a date:
where current_date - 1 <= startdate
```

If you want to disallow future dates too (as your question's title suggests), you could use a single `between` condition:

```
-- if startdate is a timestamp:
where startdate between current_timestamp - interval '1 day' and current_timestamp

-- if startdate is a date:
where startdate between current_date - 1 and current_date
```

Comment: These will come up true if startdate is in the future.

Comment: @Schwern yes, but I don't see any intent in the original query to disallow any future `startdate`s. Such data might not exists, so it's probably safe to don't even mention in the query. If they are exist, OP can use a simple between, like `startdate between current_timestamp - interval '1 day' and current_timestamp`

Comment: @Schwern F.ex. if the OP has a log-like table, which has only past dates (never future dates), the condition which removes future dates might mean more harm than help.

Comment: @Schwern startdate can't be a future date. Since its the date the record has been created.

Comment: @pozs Yes, but we don't know what their data is.  It could be scheduled events.  You can't make that assumption.  The OP asked for the last 24 hours.  If you're answering a different question, discuss why you chose to alter their question.  Else the OP may not realize the query doesn't do what they asked for.

Comment: @Pirinthan If you're making that assumption put a constraint on the table to ensure it's true.  `CHECK( starttime::timestamptz <= NOW() )`.  Otherwise there's nothing stopping a future date to be inserted via a bug or deliberate data hackery.